# A polygonal path on a normed linear space

Tags: normed-spaces

This from Book "Analysis for Applied Mathematics"- W. E. Cheney, Ex 1.2, Problem 24

> Let $<a,b> = \{\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b:0 \leq \lambda \leq 1\}$ be a line segment in a linear space. A polygonal path joining points $a$ and $b$ is any finite union of line segments $\cup_{i=1}^{n}<a_{i},a_{i+1}>$ where $a_{1} = a$ and $a_{n+1} = b$. If the linear space has a norm, the length of the polygonal path is $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\|a_{i} - a_{i+1}\|$. Give an example of a pair of points $a,b$ in a normed linear space and a polygonal path joining them such that the polygonal path is not identical to $<a,b>$ but has the same length.

This has stumped me for a long time now. How is it possible without violating the triangle inequality on the norms?

The question, then proceeds as

> A path of length $\|a-b\|$ connecting $a$ and $b$ is called a geodesic path. Prove that any geodesic polygonal path connecting $a$ and $b$ is conatined in the set $\{x:\|x-a\|\leq\|b-a\|\}$

I'm more concerned with the example. The second part of the question is for completion's sake.

Comment: Just take an intermediate point $c$ on the line segment $\langle a , b \rangle$. Then $\langle a , c \rangle \cup \langle c , b \rangle$ is not the same as $\langle a , b \rangle$ (it is as a set, but not as a polygonal line!), and the triangle inequality is verified.

Comment: Actually, I can't accept this answer, because its the most obvious one. More so, since the definition already state that the polygonal path is a union. So the argument that $<a,c>\cup<c,b>$ is different from $<a,b>$ as a polygonal path is not convincing to me.

Comment: @AlexM.: Ok I get it now. A line segment is characterized by the end points, $a,b$ & $\lambda: 0 \geq \lambda \leq 1$. Yes in that sense, the union of line segments between say $<a,\frac{a+b}{2}>$ and $<\frac{a+b}{2},b>$ is different from $<a,b>$. Thanks. It turns out to be  much ado about nothing.